# Is it possible to force a software-based "redock" for laptop docking station?

Tags: laptop, docking-station

I apologize in advance because I'm asking for a software fix to a hardware problem, so I understand if this may not be possible at all.

I have a couple weird issues with my laptop (Lenovo T460s) that I isolated to my docking station (https://www.lenovo.com/us/en/accessories-and-monitors/docking/mechanical-docks/ThinkPad-Ultra-Dock-90-W/p/40A20090US):

1. When booting up, laptop will freeze at BIOS boot screen if any USB devices are plugged into docking station. This seems to be a common problem people have been reporting for years, and Lenovo keeps claiming that latest firmware fixes the issue but it never does. I don't expect Linux to be able to do anything about this one.
2. Same docking station randomly forgets about external monitors about once/month, it literally stops sending input to them while duping the laptop and Xorg into thinking everything is OK. I kept rebooting my laptop until I isolated the issue to the docking station as well, now I just redock.

The problem is that my laptop (and dock) sits under a glass desk, and physically redocking it is a PITA. Is it possible to use a Linux utility to send a signal to the docking station to trick it into thinking that laptop has been disconnected and reconnected?

Similarly (and this may fix problem 1), is it possible to disable/enable docking port on the laptop via software (like with Wifi)? If I disable it between reboots, and reenable it after, it would fix the USB issue as well.

Comment: Use a USB hub with a switch>>>>https://www.ebay.com/b/Usb-On-Off-Switch/44932/bn_7023350206